# MapServer WMS won't show in Leaflet when STATUS ON in map file

Tags: wms, mapserver, configuration

Why won't my MapServer WMS show in Leaflet when I use `STATUS ON` in my layer in the map file, but when I change to `STATUS DEFAULT` it does,  but all layers are displayed.

```
LAYER
    NAME Jalan
    DATA mks_road
    METADATA
        WMS_TITLE "jalan"
        WMS_SRS "EPSG:4326"
    END
    STATUS ON
    TYPE LINE
    CLASS
        NAME "Jalan"
        STYLE
            COLOR 185 0 0
        END
    END
END
```

and my script is:

```
var mapserver = 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/apps/map/leaf.map&'; 
var jalan = new L.tileLayer.wms(mapserver, {
                    layers: 'jalan',
                    format: 'image/png',
                    srs: 'EPSG:4326',
                    transparent: true
                });
```

i got this statement when i use wms "GetMap" on Mapserver `msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Missing required parameter SRS`

Comment: You mention layers (plural) but your example shows only one layer.  Dealing on  a single layer basis, `status default` turns the layer on  permanently, so MapServer will always send it.

Comment: What actual request is sent to the MapServer WMS service? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: You set layer title to "jalan" but layer name is "Jalan". Use "Jalan" in GetMap. And in the future, read the GetCapabilities first.

Comment: i got this statement when i use wms "GetMap" on Mapserver

`msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Missing required parameter SRS`

Answer (score 1):

You have set Leaflet to ask for layer named "jalan" but the WMS name for that layer is "Jalan". What is used in the WMS GetMap request is the name of the layer, not the title.

You set the name with LAYER - NAME as

```
NAME Jalan
```

You set the WMS title in METADATA with

```
METADATA
WMS_TITLE "jalan"
```

The reason why the layer shows with the wrong Leaflet configuration is that when you set it to DEFAULT is that all DEFAULT layers are rendered always even if they are not asked with GetMap.